# Why doesn't furigana work in italicized or bolded text?

Tags: support, status-completed, furigana

Why can I type 漢字{かんじ}, but not *漢字{かんじ}* or **漢字{かんじ}**? Is this by design? Do I really need to use inline code formatting for kanji with furigana in italicized or bolded text?

Comment: I wouldn't really use those variants, though... I mean the emphasized one is not good looking but ok, that is personal taste. But the bold one might be a problem when reading furigana. Tiny text is hard to read when bold. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Yeah, now that you mention it, Japanese never uses italics. The rub is that it may be helpful to italicize (or emphasize) Japanese characters when they are mixed with English text formatted the same way.

Comment: Are we able to change the color of the text?  If so, instead of using bold, it might be useful to highlight the appropriate word in a color.

Comment: @Troyen No it's not possible and my guess is that it's intentional.

Comment: What about <blink>?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm jk? :)

Comment: It's been more than a year, and this is still an issue. Can we get a fix for this?

Comment: This appears to be fixed. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @Oded The examples of italics and bold in the question don't appear to be working (tested in Chrome and Firefox).  We do have a workaround that works fine, though, which you can see in jkerian's answer.

Comment: @snailboat - OK. I will remove the status tag. Do you know if this is this an issue with the script? I doubt we at SE can fix that, though if the author fixes it, we can use the updated version.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I think it's an issue with the furigana script.

Comment: @Oded this issue and others have been fixed with the updated version of the Furigana engine at http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1277 - if you've got a minute, would you be able to update the version used on the site (and if possible, add the script to the mobile site as well)?

Comment: @cypher - thanks for letting me know. An update should be happening soon.

Comment: @Oded sorry for bothering you again, but there were some people who had issue with Japanese fonts - would it be OK if you could re-update the script?

Comment: @cypher - that's been updated now.

Comment: @Oded could you please update the script with the version at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ahjjStxn? I made some changes to fix the issues at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19707/

Comment: @cypher - missed your ping... Hurray for xmas break... Updated script is up and running.

Comment: @Oded when you have a minute, would it be OK if you could update to the new version of the Furigana script, which fixes [some issues](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1495) people have been having with the script over the past year? Thanks

Comment: @Oded also, some users have been asking about mobile support for the script at http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1351.  Would it be possible to please add it to the mobile site?  I've tested it on the mobile site as well as the "full" site, so it should hopefully just be a matter of adding the `<script src="...">` tag.

Comment: @cypher - is the script in the same pastebin? If so, it still has debug enabled. In regards to the mobile site - I am not sure we can do this, as the mechanism we use for the script is used in several sites (for other custom scripts) - and is not used in the mobile theme at all. It may have implications on those sites. I will have to discuss internally before.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for your response - sorry no, the new version is at https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814 rather than pastebin.  I've previously noticed that math stackexchange has MathJax enabled on the mobile site, but looks like it might not be as easy as I thought.

Comment: @cypher - different mechanism for MathJax, as it is used in a good number of sites... We have scripts on the poker, chess, boardgames and a few other sites that use the same mechanism as here (and the anime site).

Comment: @cypher - script updated and also added to mobile versions.

Comment: @oded Thanks!  It's really great to finally have furigana working everywhere :-)

Comment: @Oded I've fixed some issues a few people were having [here](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1495) and on chat, could you please update with the new version at [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814) when you have a chance? Hopefully it'll be the last update for a while.

Comment: @cypher - updated across the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just because, **em** and **strong** tags are not under analyze list to add furigana. I will inform dev team to add those.

Answer (score 6):

Testing this variant: <b>[漢字]​{かんじ}</b>

**[漢字]{かんじ}**

Seems to work

*[漢字]{かんじ}* works as well from <i>[漢字]​{かんじ}</i>... but wow is that unreadable

Comment: [FAQ](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/808/29) entry edited.

Answer (score 5):

Admins, please consider fixing this bug.  Here is a [recent actual example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/is-%E3%82%92noun%E3%81%AB-as-in-%E3%82%92%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%AB-a-common-construct/5617#5617).

Examples:

> Without <strong> element: [漢字]{かんじ} (this works)
>   With **…** markup: **[漢字]{かんじ}** (this does not work)
>   With HTML markup: **[漢字]{かんじ}** (this does not work either)