# Fix furigana on the mobile version of our page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, furigana

Currently, we've got a script + markdown syntax for rendering *furigana*.

However, right now this works only on the desktop version of our page.

On the mobile version the markdown is displaced as-is. This is a problem because

- it makes Japanese text rather hard to read
- according to [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/japanese.stackexchange.com), 1/3 of our visitors are on mobile

Here's how a simple sentence might look like on the mobile version:

```
漠然{ばくぜん}と感{かん}じられる事{こと}を表{あらわ}す語{ご}
```

This is a short sentence and in my opinion already harder to read than this (it looks identical to the above on mobile):

```
漠然{ばくぜん}と感{かん}じられる事{こと}を表{あらわ}す語{ご}
```

Using `【】` instead of `{}` doesn't make it look much better either. See below for a longer example.

If I switch to the desktop version, *furigana* are working without performance issues on my Samsung Galaxy 3. Navigating is a lot easier on the mobile page, so we shouldn't just tell our users to switch to the desktop version.

---

**Should and can we enable furigana rendering on the mobile version of japanese.stackexchange?**

---

Here's an extreme example [from an older question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12571/3275):

[image]

Comment: I really hope this feature will be implemented, because I often use iOS App Stack Exchange to look around japanese.stackexchange.

Comment: [We finally have furigana on mobile!](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/532/why-doesnt-furigana-work-in-italicized-or-bolded-text#comment3595_532) Yippee!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [We finally have furigana on mobile! Yippee!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/why-doesnt-furigana-work-in-italicized-or-bolded-text#comment3595_532)

I can confirm it works on Android with Chrome for me too.

Answer (score 3):

YES.

I would like to hear if there's a good reason not to have it, but I'm guessing this is just extra work that someone hasn't gotten around to yet.